# Signout with ADFS3 with SAML

Tags: adfs, saml

I have implemented SSO using ADFS3. I have a logout button for sign out and it’s working fine with my ws-federation passive endpoints. On logout I redirect user to logout.aspx page and there I have written code on page load as

```
WSFederationAuthenticationModule authModule = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;

SignOutRequestMessage signOutRequestMessage = new SignOutRequestMessage(new Uri(authModule.Issuer), authModule.Realm);
            String queryString = signOutRequestMessage.WriteQueryString();
            Response.Redirect(queryString);
```

One of the applications uses SAML so I have created a SAML assertion consumer endpoint. So when I open this application and hit logout it throws an error and when I view the event log for ADFS, I see

```
Encountered error during federation passive request. 

Additional Data 

Protocol Name: 
wsfed 

Relying Party: 


Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityServer.RequestFailedException: MSIS7055: Not all SAML session participants logged out properly. It is recommended to close your browser.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.BuildSamlLogoutResponse(SamlContext samlContext, Boolean partialLogout, Boolean& logoutComplete)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.ProcessSignOut(SamlContext samlContext, String redirectUri, List`1 iFrameUris, Boolean partialLogout)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.PipelineInitiatedSignout(WrappedHttpListenerContext httpContext, String redirectUri)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.ProcessProtocolSignoutRequest(ProtocolContext protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler protocolHandler)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.ProcessProtocolRequest(ProtocolContext protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler protocolHandler)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)
```